# Is there a difference between ふたり or ににん?

Tags: readings, counters, irregularities-exceptions

In the phrase 2人組, is there any difference between the readings ２人組 【ふたりぐみ】and ２人組 【ににんぐみ】?

I found it in this sentence:

男性によると、路上飲みをしていた2人組が、そのまま路上で寝始めたといいます

*According to the man, a couple who were drinking on the street started sleeping on the street.*

https://www.fnn.jp/articles/-/580910

I find both readings here, but no explanation of the difference.

[https://jisho.org/search/2人組](https://jisho.org/search/2%E4%BA%BA%E7%B5%84)

二人組 【ににんぐみ】、２人組 【ふたりぐみ】、２人組 【ににんぐみ】

Comment: Practically speaking, ににんぐみ is rarely used. The following is an instance of ふたりぐみ in a newscasting. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ftqqMQP-gI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer in the chiebukuro](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11174788576) is very good and has all the references:

According to [this post on the NHK](https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/gimon/085.html), it could only be read as `ににんぐみ` in prior, but `ふたりぐみ` became an accepted alternative.

Also according to the book 『数え方でみがく日本語』(by [Iida Asako](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A3%AF%E7%94%B0%E6%9C%9D%E5%AD%90), published by ちくまプリマ―新書、筑摩書房), there is a tendency to use `ににんぐみ` for criminals, rather than `ふたりぐみ`, because the latter is "less menacing".

So in the case of the FNN article you brought up, `ににんぐみ` is the most common usage, and when talking about kids playing in pairs, `ふたりぐみ` is the usual way to read it.